# Estimate position of shadows cast by clouds in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, masking, azimuth, cloudmasking

I have a script for cloud masking that does its job well:

```
var START_DATE = ee.Date('2022-06-15');
var END_DATE = ee.Date('2022-07-15');
var MAX_CLOUD_PROBABILITY = 65;
var region = region_name
Map.centerObject(region, 15);

var s2Sr = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
                .filterBounds(region).filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE);
var s2Clouds = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY')
                .filterBounds(region).filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE);

function maskClouds(img) {
  var clouds = ee.Image(img.get('cloud_mask')).select('probability');
  var isNotCloud = clouds.lt(MAX_CLOUD_PROBABILITY);
  return img.updateMask(isNotCloud);
}

function maskEdges(s2_img) {
  return s2_img.updateMask(
      s2_img.select('B8A').mask().updateMask(s2_img.select('B9').mask()));
}

//Apply mask to s2Sr
s2Sr = s2Sr.map(maskEdges);

// Join S2 SR with cloud probability dataset to add cloud mask.
var s2CloudMasked = ee.Join.saveFirst('cloud_mask').apply({
  primary: s2Sr,
  secondary: s2Clouds,
  condition:
      ee.Filter.equals({leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
});

//Mask the collection
s2CloudMasked = ee.ImageCollection(s2CloudMasked).map(maskClouds);
```

As is known, Sen-2 masks ignore cloud shadows, as seen in the image below:

[image]

Since the dataset 'COPERNICUS/S2_SR' has information on incidence and solar zenith and azimuth angles, would there be a possibility of estimating the position of shadows cast by the detected cloudy pixels in order to mask them out as well?

My specific area has no relevant elevation.

As an example, the final product would then have the following areas in red also masked:

[image]

I would like to attempt this because the proposed hollstein mask is not filtering shadows in a satisfactory way. This can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

This is the Hollstein code:

```
var dt = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:decision_tree');

function hollstein_S2_shadow(img) {
    // Ref: https://github.com/fitoprincipe/geetools-code-editor/blob/master/cloud_masks
    var difference = function (a, b) {
        var wrap = function (img) {
            return img.select(a).subtract(img.select(b));
        };
        return wrap;
    };
    var ratio = function (a, b) {
        var wrap = function (img) {
            return img.select(a).divide(img.select(b));
        };
        return wrap;
    };
    //1
    var b3 = img.select('B3').lt(3190);
    //2
    var b8a = img.select('B8A').lt(1660);
    var r511 = ratio('B5', 'B11')(img).lt(4.33);
    //3
    var b3_3 = img.select('B3').lt(5250);
    var s37 = difference('B3', 'B7')(img).lt(270);
    //4
    var r15 = ratio('B1', 'B5')(img).lt(1.184);
    var s911 = difference('B9', 'B11')(img).lt(210);
    var s911_2 = difference('B9', 'B11')(img).lt(-970);

    var dtf = dt.binary({
        1: b3,
        21: b8a,
        22: r511,
        31: s37,
        34: b3_3,
        41: s911_2,
        42: s911,
        46: r15
    }, {
        'shadow-1': [
            [1, 1],
            [21, 1],
            [31, 1],
            [41, 0]
        ],
        'shadow-2': [
            [1, 1],
            [21, 1],
            [31, 0],
            [42, 0]
        ],
        'shadow-3': [
            [1, 0],
            [22, 0],
            [34, 1],
            [46, 0]
        ],
    }, 'hollstein');
    var results = dtf(img);
    return img.updateMask(results.select("shadow").not());
}
```